# What Symfony component returns Bad Credential

Tags: symfony

I'm doing an authentication provider and an user provider (ldap based). When my user enters his ID it works fine, I get role from LDAP and Symfony does a bind with user's information.

Moreover in the bottom bar I can see i'm using my own token in "Token Class" but I always receive this message "Bad credential". I think a Symfony component doesn't like what I do. I would like to know the which one?

Comment: show us your user provider class, if you have one...

Comment: The security component